# Looking for flight data from a specific United Airlines flight 25 years ago

Tags: air-travel

This is a tall order, for sure. I was on a flight from Kahului, HI to Chicago with a layover in Honolulu on August 23 or 24, 1992. There was some kind of a bomb scare in Honolulu and the flight was delayed for a few hours while they searched everyone's luggage. I am wanting more information on this flight, how long the delay was, etc. Is there ANY way I can find it without paying a 24.99 subscription fee to FlightStats...if they even have that info? I believe the carrier was United Airlines.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be local libraries that might have pre-1996 archives of Honolulu Star and/or Honolulu Advertiser ([2 newspapers with largest circulation at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honolulu_Star-Bulletin)).

Your second best bet would be contacting United Customer service. I would suggest writing them a letter, instead of calling.

[Online search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=united%20airlines%20honolulu%201992%20bomb%20threat) does not yield much.

Answer (score 4):

[Honolulu International Airport](http://hawaii.gov/hnl/airport-information/hnl-1990-1999) is owned and operated by the State of Hawaii Department of Transportation, and its website has detailed historical information throughout the decades, from 1925 to the present, including a notation of an airport closure due to a hurricane. It suggests comprehensive research and record keeping, and I would recommend contacting the airport directly dot.air.oahu@hawaii.gov or through the [Hawaii DOT Library](http://hidot.hawaii.gov/airports/library/) where an archivist may be able to help location the information.